# Redrawing a plot in IPython / matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, ipython

I use IPython/Matplotlib, and I want to create functions that can plot various graphs in the same plotting window.  However, I have trouble with redrawing.  This is my program `test_plot_simple.py`:

```
from __future__ import division
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(10)
y2 = (x**2)/(10**2)
ye = (2**x)/(2**10)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

def p_squared():
    ax.plot(x,y2, 'r')
    plt.show()

def p_exp():
    ax.plot(x,ye, 'r')
    plt.show()
```

I start IPython as `$ python --matplotlib`

On the IPython command line I do

```
In [1]: run test_plot_simple.py
In [2]: p_squared()
In [3]: p_exp()
```

After the second line, the squared graph is shown.  But nothing happens after the second.  Why is the `plt.show()` not working here?

Answer (score 1):

It appears as though you call `subplots` without actually taking advantage of them, namely that you are trying to over plot on the same canvas.  See [here](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/subplots_demo.html) for a more thorough explanation.  That being said, all you need is the following in order to have the functionality I think you want:

```
from __future__ import division
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(10)
y2 = (x**2)/(10**2)
ye = (2**x)/(2**10)

def p_squared():
    plt.plot(x,y2, 'r')
    plt.show()

def p_exp():
    plt.plot(x,ye, 'r')
    plt.show()
```

Now both the `p_squared()` and `p_exp()` calls produce plots.  Hope this helps.

Comment: This helps in the simple example.  However, for other reasons I need to go with an object-oriented approach where I can keep track of the axis from the very start.  Thus I do indeed need to do the plotting via `ax.plot()`.

Answer (score 0):

After some digging I think I found the right way to go about this.  It seems that `show()` is not really intended for this purpose, but rather `draw()` is.  And if I want to keep it object-oriented, I should draw via my figure or my axis.  It seems to me that something like this is the best approach:

```
from __future__ import division
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(10)
y2 = (x**2)/(10**2)
ye = (2**x)/(2**10)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
fig.show()

def p_squared():
    ax.plot(x,y2, 'r')
    fig.canvas.draw()

def p_exp():
    ax.plot(x,ye, 'r')
    fig.canvas.draw()
```

I.e., use `fig.canvas.draw()` in lieu of `plt.show()` (or `fig.show()`, for that matter.)

I still need one `show()` - I chose to do that right away after the figure has been created.